# Sum the several solution functions returned by DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, core-language

Could you please explain why this code does not work.

```
sxg[t_] := 
  Sum[
    Evaluate[x[[k]] /. 
        DSolve[{dx[[k]] == a[[k]], x0ui[[k]] == x0u[[k]]}, x[[k]], t]], 
    {k, 1, n}]
```

I am confused because this the following works very well:

```
Evaluate[x[[k]] /. DSolve[{dx[[k]] == a[[k]], x0ui[[k]] == x0u[[k]]}, x[[k]]
```

Can I use Evaluate inside the Sum ?
If the `Sum` function doesn't apply here, how can I add several solutions together to create a single function?

Comment: How is this different than [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111132/solve-the-n-ode-in-the-loop-add-the-solutions-to-create-one-function) you asked 14 hours ago?

Comment: I think this question is more clear and more precisely shows where the problem is. It looks like using the Table command doesn't help.

Comment: In the future, please include a fully working minimal example rather than just the code that is causing the problem. It is hard to reproduce the problem, and people here generally want to just copy and paste from the OP into their copy of *Mathematica* and run it rather than having to generate their *own* examples of symbols that are left undefined by the OP. It's not in general worth the effort (which is why you haven't had much response yet to either of your questions!). In addition, please include in your post the actual errors that *Mathematica* spits out. Provide us with complete info!

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem with your code: the issue is the `Evaluate`. By typing

```
Evaluate[x[[k]] /. DSolve[{dx[[k]] == a[[k]], x0ui[[k]] == x0u[[k]]}, x[[k]], t]]
```

inside the sum, you are trying to force *Mathematica* to evaluate the expression *before* `k` has evaluated to an integer (according to `{k, 1, n}`). Strip off the `Evaluate` and things work nicely.

The second issue is that your syntax for creating a function out of the outputs from `DSolve` is wrong. Here is a fix. I have provided an example of your variables (please do this yourself in future posts!).

```
x = Array[f, 4]
dx = Derivative[1][#][t] & /@ x
a = {-1, -2, -3, -4} Through[x[t]]
x0ui = Through[x[0]]
x0u = Range[4]
(* {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4]}
(* {Derivative[1][f[1]][t], Derivative[1][f[2]][t], Derivative[1][f[3]][t], Derivative[1][f[4]][t]} *)
(* {-f[1][t], -2 f[2][t], -3 f[3][t], -4 f[4][t]} *)
(* {f[1][0], f[2][0], f[3][0], f[4][0]} *)
(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

Then,

```
s[t_] = Sum[x[[k]] /. DSolve[{dx[[k]] == a[[k]], x0ui[[k]] == x0u[[k]]}, x[[k]], t], {k, 1, 4}]
```

returns

```
(* {Function[{t}, 4 E^(-4 t)] + Function[{t}, 3 E^(-3 t)] + Function[{t}, 2 E^(-2 t)] + Function[{t}, E^-t]} *)
```

`s[t]` will *not* be interpreted as a function of `t`, even if you strip off the extra `List`. Calling `s[1]` results in all kinds of errors.

There are two possible fixes:

```
s[t_] = Sum[x[[k]][t] /. First@DSolve[{dx[[k]] == a[[k]], x0ui[[k]] == x0u[[k]]}, x[[k]][t], t], {k, 1, 4}]
(* 4 E^(-4 t) + 3 E^(-3 t) + 2 E^(-2 t) + E^-t *)
```

or

```
s[t_] = Through[Sum[x[[k]] /. First@DSolve[{dx[[k]] == a[[k]], x0ui[[k]] == x0u[[k]]}, x[[k]], t], {k, 1, 4}][t]]
(* 4 E^(-4 t) + 3 E^(-3 t) + 2 E^(-2 t) + E^-t *)
```